# Can't find EntityAliasToClassConstantReferenceRector in rector doctrine

Tags: rector

I was using `\Rector\Doctrine\Rector\MethodCall\EntityAliasToClassConstantReferenceRector::class` to convert some 'App\Entity\MyEntity' => MyEntity::class with rector with a previous project.

When I tried using it this time, I found out that it wasn't referenced in rector-doctrine set of rules anymore.

It seems to have disappeared after version 0.14.*

I couldn't downgrade and make it work. Is there any alternatives ? Or ways to add it back ?
I tried to add a custom rule, but with my limited knowledge I couldn't pass some PHPStan missing methods.

Cheers